# Compare two columns in two dataframes which has comma separated values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting, comparison

I have a dataframe df1

```
Id Items
AQ  a,b,c
AT  z,x,y
AY  k,l,m
```

I have another df2

```
Id Items
AQ  b,c a
AT  z,y,x
AY  k,l,m,n
```

I want to compare items columns of both dfs. Simply comparing gives false because the order is different. But they have same values. How can I order and compare.
Resultant df

```
Id comparison_items
AQ  True
AT  True
AY  False
```

I tried sorting the values but I'm not getting expected result.I am writing this code in python

Comment: Do you care about multiplicity of the elements? If not, you could make a function that compares each column into a set and compares if they have the same elements that way

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if the type of the values in the "Items" column are strings or lists, but in both cases it is sufficient to apply `sorted` on this column and then compare the two DataFrames.

##### Example with lists

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Id':['AQ', 'AT', 'AY'], 'Items':[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['z', 'x', 'y'], ['k', 'l', 'm']]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Id':['AQ', 'AT', 'AY'], 'Items':[['b', 'c', 'a'], ['z', 'y', 'x'], ['k', 'l', 'm', 'n']]})

df1['Items'] = df1['Items'].apply(sorted)
df2['Items'] = df2['Items'].apply(sorted)
df1 == df2
>>>   Id    Items
0   True    True
1   True    True
2   True    False
```

##### Example with strings

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Id':['AQ', 'AT', 'AY'], 'Items':['a,b,c', 'z,x,y', 'k,l,m']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Id':['AQ', 'AT', 'AY'], 'Items':['b,c,a', 'z,y,x', 'k,l,m,n']})

# maybe a bit cleaner, but still giving the same result
# df1['Items'] = df1['Items'].apply(lambda x: sorted(x.split(',')))
# df2['Items'] = df2['Items'].apply(lambda x: sorted(x.split(',')))

df1['Items'] = df1['Items'].apply(sorted)
df2['Items'] = df2['Items'].apply(sorted)
df1 == df2
>>>   Id    Items
0   True    True
1   True    True
2   True    False
```

To get the wanted result, you can use

```
df = df1.assign(comparison_items = df1['Items']==df2['Items']).drop('Items', axis=1)
df
>>> Id  comparison_items
0   AQ  True
1   AT  True
2   AY  False
```